# Comparison before aggregation of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

Say I have the following data frame and I would like to aggregate it. In doing so, I need some extra steps:

- For addable columns, simply add up for the same ID.
- For non-addable columns, first compare the entries for the same ID and set the value in aggregation to be the larger one. For example, for `ID="a"`, I need Date to be 1989.
- For characters, if they are the same for the same ID, then just use any entry; if not, then paste them together with space as the aggregated entry.

```
x <- data.frame(ID=c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), 
            Addable=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 5), 
            Date=c(1988, 1989, 2000, 2011, 2011),
            Char=c("good", "good", "fine", "yes", "no"))
```

How to do so? Especially the comparison part as well as the character part. Eventually, the results I need is as follows:

```
 ID Addable Date   Char
  a       3 1989   good
  b       3 2000   fine
  c       6 2011 yes_no
```

Comment: Can you please add your expected output for the sample data you provide?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Updated the question, any suggestion on how to deal with the character part?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `sqldf`, then the following raw SQL query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(Addable) AS addable_sum,
    MAX(Date) AS max_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(DISTINCT Char, '', ''), '_') AS Char
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Here is R code you may try:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT ID, SUM(Addable) AS addable_sum, MAX(Date) AS max_date,
          GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(DISTINCT Char, '', ''), '_') AS Char
          FROM x GROUP BY ID"

result <- sqldf(sql)
```

Comment: I think you need to make one small change so that variable Char for ID==a is 'good' and not 'good_good'.

Comment: One small problem, what if the column name contain "."? For example, "ID.x". It seems that sqldf does not accept this name and produced error message Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such column: ID.x

Comment: @LaTeXFan `ID.x` makes no sense, maybe you meant `x.ID`?  You specify the table name, or table alias, _first_, followed by the column name, not the other way around.

Comment: @milan What do you mean? How to make changes?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen All I am saying is that the data provided to me have column names containing "." and this seems to cause problems. I guess I can change the column names first. But is there a way to get around without doing so?

Comment: Yes, you can try putting the fully qualified name in double quotes.  But, you'll have to escape those double quotes if they also appear inside a string.  I don't have your real data, so I can't (and shouldn't have to again) update my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried your code once add in DISTINCT. I got the error Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  DISTINCT aggregates must have exactly one argument

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `tidyverse` package

```
x %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(addable = sum(Addable), date = max(Date)) 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ID    addable  date
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a           3  1989
 2 b           3  2000
 3 c           6  2011
```

Comment: After edit: @tmfmnk write correct answer so I don't want to duplicate it.

Answer (score 1):

Could try this. `base R` solution using `aggregate`. For the `Char` variable we can use a combination of `paste0` and `unique`.

```
a1 <- aggregate(Addable ~ ID, x, function(x) sum(x))
a2 <- aggregate(Date ~ ID, x, function(x) max(x))
a3 <- aggregate(Char ~ ID, x, function(x) paste0(unique(x)))
merge(merge(a1, a2), a3)

  ID Addable Date    Char
1  a       3 1989    good
2  b       3 2000    fine
3  c       6 2011 yes, no
```

Comment: In my code it was not a problem, as you can see from the output. ‘unique’ does that.

Comment: Is there way to change Tim's code for the same result?

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution covering also the character part:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Char = paste0(unique(Char), collapse = "_")) %>%
  summarise(Addable = sum(Addable),
            Date = max(Date),
            Char = last(Char))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID    Addable  Date Char  
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 a          3. 1989. good  
2 b          3. 2000. fine  
3 c          6. 2011. yes_no
```

Answer (score 1):

### base R using `by`

```
do.call(rbind, by(x, x$ID, function(.) data.frame(
         ID=.$ID[1],
         Addable = sum(.$Addable),
         Date = max(.$Date),
         Char = paste(unique(.$Char), collapse=", "),
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
))

# Output
#   ID Addable Date    Char
# a  a       3 1989    good
# b  b       3 2000    fine
# c  c       6 2011 yes, no
```

### base R + magrittr

```
# for fun only -- adding a tidyverse flavour
x %>% 
  by(x$ID, force) %>% 
  lapply(function(.) data.frame(
    Addable = sum(.$Addable),
    Date = max(.$Date),
    Char = paste(unique(.$Char), collapse=", ")
    )) %>% 
  do.call(rbind,.)
```